# Adding/inserting different texts to specific intervals of same text file?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, command, text

I know how to insert a single text to specific interval. But now my problem is, I want to insert different texts/words saved in an `add.txt` file to a specific intervals of another `data.txt` file.

I want to insert first word from `add.txt` to a specific position of `data.txt`, then add second word from `add.txt` to next specific position and so on.

My `data.txt` contain two columns, but the inserted word must appear as a merged row. Please see the example below of what I need.

`add.txt`

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00 42 1
2001-01-02 00:00:00 42 1
2001-01-03 00:00:00 42 1
2001-01-04 00:00:00 42 1
2001-01-05 00:00:00 42 1
```

`data.txt`

```
  -500      11.822788
  -400      12.006394
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.793395
  -500      11.823597
  -400      12.008012
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.794204
  -500      11.826023
  -400      12.011247
  -350      12.291915
  -300      12.800675
  -500      11.827641
  -400      12.013674
  -350      12.295959
  -300      12.805528
  -500      11.830067
  -400      12.016100
  -350      12.300003
  -300      12.811998
```

I want

```
2001-01-01 00:00:00 42 1 
 -500      11.822788
  -400      12.006394
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.793395
2001-01-02 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.823597
  -400      12.008012
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.794204
2001-01-03 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.826023
  -400      12.011247
  -350      12.291915
  -300      12.800675
2001-01-04 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.827641
  -400      12.013674
  -350      12.295959
  -300      12.805528
2001-01-04 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.830067
  -400      12.016100
  -350      12.300003
  -300      12.811998
```

I am looking for a simplest solution using `awk`, `sed` or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ awk '(FNR-1)%4 == 0 { getline add <"add.txt"; print add }; 1' data.txt
2001-01-01 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.822788
  -400      12.006394
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.793395
2001-01-02 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.823597
  -400      12.008012
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.794204
2001-01-03 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.826023
  -400      12.011247
  -350      12.291915
  -300      12.800675
2001-01-04 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.827641
  -400      12.013674
  -350      12.295959
  -300      12.805528
2001-01-05 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.830067
  -400      12.016100
  -350      12.300003
  -300      12.811998
```

This uses `awk` to read and output every line of the `data.txt` file. Before outputting any 4th line, a line is read and outputted from the `add.txt` file.

No check is made to verify that the data read from `add.txt` is correctly read (if the file is too short, the above code would repeat the last line).

---

Using `paste`:

```
$ paste -d '\n' add.txt - - - - <data.txt
2001-01-01 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.822788
  -400      12.006394
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.793395
2001-01-02 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.823597
  -400      12.008012
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.794204
2001-01-03 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.826023
  -400      12.011247
  -350      12.291915
  -300      12.800675
2001-01-04 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.827641
  -400      12.013674
  -350      12.295959
  -300      12.805528
2001-01-05 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.830067
  -400      12.016100
  -350      12.300003
  -300      12.811998
```

Here, I ask `paste` to create records with a line from `add.txt` as the first field, followed by four lines from `data.txt` as the next four fields. With `-d '\n'` I set the character to use as a field delimiter  to a newline character.

Comment: ♦ wow! that did the job. Many thanks and much appreciated.

Comment: The `paste` option seems more handy. But what should do if my intervals are large, say, 500? Is there any alternative for dashes `----` in this case?

Comment: @linux_lover Not really. The `paste` variation is really only useful for smaller intervals like the one in your question. There is no way to "abbreviate" the column specification with `paste`.

Comment: That make sense. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 3):

If `GNU sed` is an option, especially for those on MacOS, we can run the following sed code. The R command and the ~ command, which are gnu additions are the key here.

The ~ will make sed look at every fourth line specially, for others it will pass through to stdout. The R shall take one line from add.txt and mix it with the data.txt line.

```
$ sed '
    1~4!b
    R add.txt
    $!N
' data.txt
```

Comment: Great! I tested this and came out well as I needed. Thanks for the solution using `sed` command.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the simplest approach is just to read add.txt into an array and then print a line from the array every 4 lines of data.txt:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0; next} FNR%4==1{print a[++c]} 1' add.txt data.txt
2001-01-01 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.822788
  -400      12.006394
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.793395
2001-01-02 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.823597
  -400      12.008012
  -350      12.287062
  -300      12.794204
2001-01-03 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.826023
  -400      12.011247
  -350      12.291915
  -300      12.800675
2001-01-04 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.827641
  -400      12.013674
  -350      12.295959
  -300      12.805528
2001-01-05 00:00:00 42 1
  -500      11.830067
  -400      12.016100
  -350      12.300003
  -300      12.811998
```

Comment: You might have to contend with using quite a bit more memory than in Kusalananda's solution in case file `add.txt` is very large. Kind of a corner case though. ;-)

Comment: @Ed Morton your solution is also working smoothly. Many thanks.

Comment: @Cbhihe Thanks for pointing that out. I am asking this for a clarity: So, you are saying that the solution given by Kusalananda and Ed Morton will not work with very large `add.txt`?Then what will be the solution that will even work for larger `add.txt`? Because in near-future I will work with larger `add.txt` kind-of files.

Comment: @linux_lover: I never said  or meant to say that kusalananda's or, for that matter, EdMorton's solution would not work for large files. I only do say that the latter would need more memory for large `add.txt` files (because in EdMorton's solution the whole file os parsed into his array).  For that to be an issue you would probably have to run up `add.txt` file in the 10s of GB. So i do not believe it is relevant. In a nutshell, both solutions are fine and Kulasananda is likely to use less memory when executing. Is all.

Comment: linux_lover you asked for the simplest solution, not the most robust, or portable or efficient or anything else solution - careful what you wish for! When you talk about a "large" file in the comments above, "large" isn't a problem, "absolutely massive" would be a problem. As @Cbhihe says it'd have to be 10s of gigabytes before it'd be a problem, if your file is just a few million lines then it'd work just fine. There are other differences between how the scripts would handle cases such as add.txt not having as many lines as 1/4 the lines in data.txt and there would be efficiency differences.